# Couunt parent nodes inside grandparent from child. XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml file like this.

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>Text</d>
        </c>
        <c>
            <d>Text</d>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>Text</d>
        </c>
        <c>
            <d>Text</d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I'm in `<d>` node and i need to get the number of `<c>` node inside `<b>`. Be aware that this is just a sample so we can have deeper structure and `<c>` will not be direct parent of `<d>`. 
So, what i need. I need to have in first `<d>` node 1 (because we inside `<c>` and it is first in `<b>`) in the second 2, in third 1 and in fourth 2. We don't need to count all `<c>` elements but only parents of current `<d>` inside parent `<b>`.

For now i have 
count(preceding::c) . But it counts all 4 `<c>` nods.

Please help. Thank you.

P.S. I'm using xsl 1.0

Comment: `preceding` is the wrong axis. Maybe a visualization of XPath axes helps you understand. http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/inet-2005/images/xpath-axis.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to have in first `<d>` node 1 (because we inside `<c>` and it is first in `<b>`)

So you need to go up the tree to the current node's `c` ancestor and then count the number of that element's preceding `c` siblings:

```
count(ancestor::c[1]/preceding-sibling::c) + 1
```

The +1 is because the first `c` in a given `b` will have no preceding siblings, the second will have one, etc.

To ensure you go up the tree to the `c` that is a child of `b` (e.g. if there may be other elements named `c` in between) you can be more specific

```
count(ancestor::c[parent::b][1]/preceding-sibling::c) + 1
```

to target only a `c` that itself has a `b` as its parent.

Comment: Thank you man. You've saved me a lot of time. Sorry for not voting up. I don't have enough reputation yet (

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the level you want to go to and count the children.

```
count(../../c)
```

or

```
count(ancestor::b[1]/c)
```

Comment: First is not suitable for my case because as i said i'm inside `<c>`. Second is not working for me because it's return the total number of `<c>` nodes. In the example will be 4.

Comment: No, you said, and I quote: *"I'm in `<d>` node and i need to get the number of `<c>` node inside `<b>`"*. And this is *exactly* what my answer does. Maybe you should have described the problem better.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. But in this case i have sample data. So, in the real world i can have not the same structure, and up/up level will not work. Anyway, thanks for answering.