# Numerate same nodes inside top level parent. XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This question is similar to 
[Couunt parent nodes inside grandparent from child. XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854477/couunt-parent-nodes-inside-grandparent-from-child-xsl). But that one is a little bit different, that's why i've created new one.
So, i have xml like this (Note! this is sample xml, so the structure can be different).

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>     
      <d>    
        text
      </d>    
    </c>    
    <b>    
      <c>    
        <d>
          text    
        </d>   
      </c>
    </b>        
  </b>    
</a>
```

And i need to count `<c>` nodes inside top level `<b>` like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>     
      <d>    
        text c number 1
      </d>    
    </c>    
    <b>    
      <c>    
        <d>
          text c number 2  
        </d>   
      </c>
    </b>        
  </b>    
</a>
```

and so on. If i'll have deeper structure, still i need to count all `<c>` inside top level `<b>` and place the number of it into `<d>`.
Note! I'm inside `<d>`, so i need to count from it.

Currently i have this code `count(ancestor::b[last()]/descendant::c/preceding-sibling::c)` but it's not working ((

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are we allowed to use the fact that the outermost `<b>` is a child of `<a>`?

Comment: Unfortunately `<b>` can have different parents.

Comment: But if you want to select top level `<b>` use this - `ancestor::b[last()]`.

Comment: But this breaks, if e.g. `<a>` has two children of type `<b>`, doesn't it? Then, there is no unique toplevel `<b>`. In this case, would you like to restart enumeration for each top level `<b>` or shall the enumeration span all top level `<b>`?

Comment: Yes, i like to restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the template for c/d, I'd write

```
<xsl:number level="any" 
            count="c" 
            from="ancestor::b[parent::*[not(parent::*)]]"/>
```

to get the number of the parent c element, within the second-level b element.